# adjusting aspect ratio in python

Tags: aspect-ratio

I'm trying to adjust the aspect ratio for my triangle. I used various ways but one way or another it doesn't produce what I need.
The code is here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
# Geometry of the system
# x coordinate
x = [1, 62.5, 124, 1]
# y coordinate
y = [1, 36, 1, 1]

plt.axis('equal')
aspect_ratio = (max(x) - min(x)) / (max(y) - min(y))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6 / aspect_ratio))
plt.plot(x, y, color='black', alpha=1, linewidth=1)

plt.xlabel("y", fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("z", fontsize=18)

plt.ylim(0, 38)  # Set lower limit to 0
plt.xlim(0, 125)
plt.savefig("triangle_plot.png")
#plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

It plots the triangle for me and the aspect ratio is correct, but the horizontal axis is cut and fully shown, which I can't manage to fix. Can someone help me with fixing it? A figure is attached for your consideration.

Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHCba.png)